# Break an Each statement once an inside IF statement is run once in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, if-statement, each, break

In the following code how do I break the `each` statement once the `if` code successfully changes the very first 1 it comes across to 2.

```
hash = {:key1 => "1", :key2 => "2", :key3 => "1", :key4 => "3" :key5 => "3"}
array = [:key1,:key2,:key3,:key4,:key5]
array.each do |x|
if hash[x] == "1"
hash[x] = 2
end
```

Comment: `x` is a block variable. It does not exist outside of the block. That means, your whole `each` block is equivalent to doing nothing. Purpose of your code is not clear.

Comment: I changed my code to further explain my issue @sawa

Comment: @RavensFlock  have given you the idea,why not using this?

Answer (score 0):

Something like below you want

```
array = [1,2,2,1,2]
array.each do |x|
  break x = 2 if x == 1
end
```

Comment: If I wanted it to display puts x after x is assigned 2 where would I place that? @arup